# Confusion about the least upper bound property

Tags: general-topology, supremum-and-infimum

We say an ordered set $S$ has the least upper bound property if every nonempty subset of $S_0$ of $S$ that is bounded above has a least upper bound.

Let $A = (-1,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Does $A$ have the least upper bound property? Well, let $A_0$ be any nonempty subset of $A$. If $A_0$ is bounded above, then $\exists a \in A$ such that $\forall x \in A_0, x \le a$. Now clearly, $x \le 1$, but $1 \not\in A$. So how do we we deal with this? We assume (or prove) $\mathbb{R}$ has the least upper bound property. So assuming that it does, then every bounded above subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly $(-1,1)$ is a bounded above subset of $\mathbb{R}$, since $\forall x \in (-1,1), x \le 1$, so it has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$, but not in $A$?

Similarly, why doesn't $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ have the least upper bound property?

Comment: Be careful about the precise statement of a 'least upper bound property"!  If a set of real numbers has an upper bound then it has a least upper bound.  It does NOT say the least upper bound must be IN that set!

Comment: @GeorgeIvey I understand that. The set $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ should have a least upper bound $1$. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: The least upper bound needs to be in $\mathbb{R}$. $1$ is a real number. But the least upper bound does not need to belong to $(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$. Have you learnt about Cauchy sequences and all that stuff?

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern No. I'm just wondering why $(-1,1)$ has the property, but why $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ doesn't.

Comment: But $(-1,1)$ doesn't have that property. It has least upper bound $1$ but $1 \notin (-1,1)$. However, $1$ is a real number.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern https://i.imgur.com/ogVxXWM.png

Comment: That seems to be a mistake, unless I am reading this entirely incorrectly

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern I mean, I hope so? That would make me feel better, at the very least.

Comment: "The set (−1,0)∪(0,1) should have a least upper bound 1. Why doesn't that work?"  It DOES!  1 "should" be the least upper bound and IT IS!

Comment: You seem to be confusing the questions "What is the least upper bound of this set" and "Does this set have the least upper bound property".  The set of all real numbers HAS the least upper bound property but does NOT have a least upper bound.  The set of all rational numbers from 1 to 2 HAS a least upper bound, 2, but does NOT have the least upper bound property.

Answer (score 1):

Considered as a subset of $(-1, 1)$, the set $(-1, 1)$ is not bounded.

The precise statement we are looking for is as follows:

Consider a partially ordered set $(A, \leq)$. A subset $B \subseteq A$ is said to be $(A, \leq)$-bounded from above iff there exists some $a \in A$ such that $\forall b \in B (b \leq a)$. When $(A, \leq)$ is clear from context, we just use the term “bounded from above”.

In particular, we see that $(-1, 1)$ is $(\mathbb{R}, \leq)$-bounded from above, since $1$ is an upper bound. However, $(-1, 1)$ is not $((-1, 1), \leq)$-bounded from above since there is no upper bound of $(-1, 1)$ in $(-1, 1)$.

The least-upper-bound property states that for all $B \subseteq A$, if $B$ is non-empty and $(A, \leq)$-bounded from above, then there is some $a \in A$ which is the least upper bound of $B$. In particular, $\mathbb{R}$ has the least upper bound property. Since $(-1, 1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are order-isomorphic, $(-1, 1)$ also has the least upper bound property.

Comment: Then why doesn't $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ have the least upper bound property?

Comment: Because $(-1,0)$ does not have a least upper bound within $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ but it does have upper bounds like $\frac 12$

Comment: @RossMillikan “$(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ does have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$, so why can't we use the same argument as we did for $(-1,1)$?

Comment: because $(-1,1)$ does not have an upper bound in the set, so it does not need to have a least upper bound.

Comment: @RossMillikan But it still has the least upper bound property..

Comment: @politeproofs The set $(-1, 0)$ is $((-1, 0) \cup (0, 1), \leq)$-bounded from above. One such upper bound is $1/2$. However, $(-1, 0)$ does not have a least upper bound.

Comment: @MarkSaving I'm confused as to how I was supposed to easily know that (why it works for $(-1,1) but not the other interval) from [this](https://i.imgur.com/ogVxXWM.png) text? The lack of emphasis makes me think that it should be apparent

Comment: The point is that the upper bounds and least upper bounds need to be part of the set.  The whole set $(-1,1)$ has the property because if you have a set of points converging to $1$ the set has no upper bound in the set.  If you have a set of points that does not converge to $1$ it has an upper bound and a least upper bound in the set $(-1,1)$.  The difference with $(-1,0)$ *as a part of $(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$ is that it has an upper bound in the set, many of them.  $1/2$ is one.

Comment: It has no least upper bound in the set $(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$ because its least upper bound in the reals is $0$, which is not part of the set.

Comment: @RossMillikan This is not a valid deduction. $(-1, 0)$ has a least upper bound in $(-1, 0) \cup \{1\}$ even though $0$, its supremum in $\mathbb{R}$, is not in $(-1, 0) \cup \{1\}$.

Comment: @MarkSaving:  good point